# Using "var X = document.getElementById("X");" to collect var from form

Tags: ajax, getelementbyid

Great site, superb contributors, I thank you in advance.

(rant)>72 hours, 50% less hair, googling ".ajax easy examples" = There are no easy, working examples on the web - :-)(/rant)

I'm collecting data from a form, passing that data to a javascript routine, that launches a php file that writes to my DB. EVERYTHING works VERY nice - here is the SIMPLE, WORKING script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#submitbutton").click(function() {

var ln = 'DaVinci';
var fn = 'Leonardo';
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testbackendinsert.php",
        data: {lastname: ln, firstname: fn}
       })
        .done( function( msg ) {alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );});

});
});     
</script>
```

I can put any string into the ln and fn variables and the data ends up in the db.

When I put my form in (EASY, one input, one button):

```
<form><table>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" id="fn" name="FirstName"></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table></form>
```

and use the line

```
var ln = document.getElementById("fn");
```

in place of the var ln = "Somedudesname";
It doesn't work, or CRASHES (yes, crashes, hangs) IE (I have to close and reopen).
I've tried ("fn"), ('fn'), (#fn), ('#fn'), ("#fn") and no go.
I'm sure it's something trivial (it always is) - what am I missing?

### Thanks very much!

### Here's the entire code:

HTML/JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<title>test ajax frontend</title>

<style>
#divtest {
    width:40%;
    background-color:#C1C1FD;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    border: 20px solid #FCD1E3;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="divtest">
<form>
<table>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="fn" name="FirstName"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="ln" name="FirstName"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Zip code:</td><td><input type="text" id="zp" name="FirstName"></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#submitbutton").click(function() {

var ln = document.getElementById("ln").value;
var fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
var zp = document.getElementById("zp").value;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testbackendinsert.php",
        data: {lastname: ln, firstname: fn, zip: zp}
       })
        .done( function( msg ) {alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );});

});
});     
</script>

<!--
document.getElementById("fn")
document.getElementById("ln")
-->

</body>
```

### And here is the php that writes to the db:

```
<?php
echo "<title>Read db table.php</title>";

$ln = $_POST['lastname'];
$fn = $_POST['firstname'];
$z = $_POST['zip'];

$host = "name of host";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}
echo "connection made";

$query = "INSERT INTO testtable (lastname, firstname, zip) VALUES ('$ln', '$fn', '$z')";

$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("No query");
mysqli_close($cxn);
?>
```

Happy coding to everyone!
And thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to get the value of that element:

```
var ln = document.getElementById("fn").value;
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var ln = $("#fn").val();
```

Comment: It works great, and if I can figure out how to add it, I'll put the entire code here for other newbies such as myself - thank you again.

Comment: @TimSPQR: Also, your MySQL query is insecure. Look into "prepared statements": http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are looking for:

```
var ln = document.getElementById("fn").value
```

to get the value of the input. `.getElementById()` will only store the element itself in the var and not the value property.

Comment: Superb! Thank you also Vanthel!